# Java Play 2.4 and IDEA - Views not resolving

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am doing everything pretty standard. Trying to use the Play-Authenticate plugin, but my references to several views won't resolve.

The import is there, but it is grayed out, showing it is unused. This is what my build.sbt looks like:

```
name := """WebApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.feth" % "play-authenticate_2.11" % "0.7.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.2.0",
  "be.objectify" % "deadbolt-java_2.11" % "2.4.4"
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator


fork in run := true
```

I have tried restarting intellij, running sbt clean, reloading the project from existing sources.

It's odd because when I alt+enter it knows what import to suggest, but even when it pulls it in, it still is unresolved. Ex:

```
return ok(unverified.render());
```

becomes:

```
return ok(views.html.account.signup.unverified.render());
```

but it is still unresolved.

Comment: Have you ran the project? The compiled templates are only generated on run.

Comment: I would restart the IDE and then while importing the project , I would check the 'Auto Import' option for SBT. I had the same problems several times and a new import solved all the problems.

Comment: Which versions of IntelliJ IDEA and Scala Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The only method I've found that consistently works is manually changing the classpath.

1. Open Project Structure
2. Select the module containing the templates.  If you have a multi-module project, apply this to each.
3. Expand `target/scala-2.11/twirl`.  It's possible these are excluded (red icon).
4. Change the exclusions to un-exclude `twirl` (yellow icon).  Inside `twirl`, mark `main` as a source root.

[image]